# When the string is number C language

Tags: c, char

I want to return nothing when the string is number
here is my code,

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int num = 0;

char* findWord(char* subString) {
        char* word = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(subString) + 1));
        int i = 0;
        int Position = 0;
        num = 0;


        while (ispunct(subString[i]) != 0 || isspace(subString[i]) != 0) {
                i++;
        }
        num = i;

        while (ispunct(subString[i]) == 0 && isspace(subString[i]) == 0) {
                word[Position] = subString[i];
                i++;
                Position++;
        }

        word[Position] = '\0';
        return word;
}

char** wordList(const char* s) {
        int len = strlen(s);
        int i = 0;
        char* Copyword = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
        strncpy(Copyword, s, len);
        char** result = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (len + 1));    
        char* word = NULL;

        word = findWord(Copyword);
        char* wordEnd = Copyword;

        while (*word != 0) {
                result[i] = word;              
                wordEnd = wordEnd + strlen(word) + num;
                word = findWord(wordEnd);              
                i++;
        }
        result[i] = '\0';
        free(Copyword);
        return result;
}

int main(void) {
        char** words = wordList("1 23 456 789");
        int i = 0;
        while (words[i] != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", words[i]);
                free(words[i]); // We're done with that word
                i++;
        }
        free(words); // We're done with the list
        return 0;
 }
```

my code is ok when the string is sentence.
however, in this case, I want to print nothing(just like a  space) when the string is number.
but what I go is

```
1
23
456
789
```

I expect to get

```
nothing shows here! just a space
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! This site is a Q&A site, so you're expected to actually 1/ ask a question about a _specific_ problem 2/ show what you're trying to solve your problem and get help with _issues_ you might have in doing so. And doing so, we appreciate getting a minimal concise verifiable example that emphasizes your issue.

Comment: That said, what is your _actual_ issue? Your code is indeed fine, but it is not designed for skipping words made of numbers. You might want to modify your `findWord()` function to actually do so. Did you try something? Are you having issues doing it? Did you try usinc [isdigit()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) in your `findWord()` function to skip words only made of digits?

Comment: Code is likely to have UB as `Copyword` is allocated memory equal to length of string `s` and all of this memory is filled .NO  space for `'\0'`. So in `malloc(strlen(s)+1)` should be done.

Comment: for this question isdigit() include 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F I only want if the string is number what  else founction I can use?

Answer (score 0):

For starters: You pass a non `0`-terminated C-"string" (`Copyword`) to `findWord()` and in there call `strlen()` on it. This just doesn't crash your app by bad luck.

Comment: May you tell me how I can improve my code. I know I need some condition in my findword but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @user3624415: You might like to read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn how to help yourself.